# Python whats the difference between these 2 lines?

Tags: python, csv, newline

Can someone tell me the difference between **`lineterminator='\n'`** and **`newline=''`** in the 2 instances below?

1:

```
data=[person,age]
with open(document.csv, 'a') as file:
    writing = csv.writer(file, lineterminator='\n')
    wr.writerow(data)
```

2:

```
data=[person,age]
with open(document.csv, 'a', newline='') as file:
    writing = csv.writer(file)
    wr.writerow(data)
```

When viewing the csv file, both result in the same output...

Comment: Have you tried reading the documenation?

Comment: @MartijnPieters i have

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two options do **not** produce the same file output on Linux or Mac. Only on Windows will you see the same output.

The first instructs the `csv` module to write `\n` as the line terminator between lines. The file object it is writing to, being in text mode, will then translate that terminator to the *platform default*. The default is `\n` on Linux or Mac, but it is `\r\n` on Windows.

The second piece instructs the *file object* to not change the line endings being written to it (it would otherwise translate line separators). The `csv` module is left to the default, so it'll write two `\r\n` characters between lines. The result is that all lines are terminated with `\r\n` regardless of the platform.

See the [`Dialect.lineterminator` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.lineterminator):

> The string used to terminate lines produced by the `writer`. It defaults to `'\r\n'`.

and the [`open()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open):

> When writing output to the stream, if *newline* is None, any `'\n'` characters written are translated to the system default line separator, `os.linesep`. If newline is `''` or `'\n'`, no translation takes place. If newline is any of the other legal values, any `'\n'` characters written are translated to the given string.

Comment: Anyone one you would see best to use?

Comment: @pythontamer:  Use `newline=''`. You can then still instruct the CSV module to use a different line terminator *on top of that*.